# Count the selected dropdowns in gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview, drop-down-menu

I have a gridview which contains dropdown listboxes in a column, say the dropdown has values, `'A','B' and 'C'`. Also, I have a column for `student names`.(Say there are some 10 students).

**I want to get the count of the no. of students who selected 'A' as the value from dropdown.**

Is this possible?

**EDIT:**
This is the code for my dropdown. I haven't made a beginning for the validation as yet.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Choose Employer" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-Width="15%">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="cboEmployer" CssClass="textEntry" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="cboEmployer_SelectedIndexChanged" onclick="javascript:shouldsubmit=false;" Width="80%"></asp:DropDownList>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: show me code of your `save` button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a button after your GridView . In the Submit click event you can access Gridviews dropdownlist values

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender , eventArgs e)
{
  int count=0;
  foreach(GridViewRow row in gridViewId.Rows)
  {
    DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("cboEmployer");
    string selectedValue = ddl.SelectedValue.ToString();
    if(selectedValue  == "A")
       count++;
  }
  Response.Write("Number of values selected as A : "+ count);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion:
If you are interpreting this after the form has been submitted and drop down value is saved in database then you can always extract that value from database against the name of students who selected that drop down value using simple count(*) query.

Comment: No I do this before the Save.

Comment: Then can you please show the code in JSfiddle or plunker?

Answer (score 0):

In your code I don't understand use of `onclick="javascript:shouldsubmit=false;`
and why you have made `AutoPostBack="true"`.

I think you should use dropdown list as simple

**Use this,**

```
 <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="cboEmployer" CssClass="textEntry" Width="80%">  
 </asp:DropDownList>
```

**Instead of this**

```
 <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="cboEmployer" CssClass="textEntry" 
  AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="cboEmployer_SelectedIndexChanged" 
  onclick="javascript:shouldsubmit=false;" Width="80%"></asp:DropDownList>
```

Make other dropdown in as above manner.
The code for making count in `save` button is as follow:

```
 protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, eventArgs e)
    {
        int countA = 0, countB = 0, countC = 0;

        foreach (GridViewRow row in gridViewId.Rows)
        {
            DropDownList cboEmployer = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("cboEmployer");

            string selectedValue = cboEmployer.SelectedValue;

            if (selectedValue == "A")
            {
                countA++;
            }
            else if (selectedValue == "B")
            {
                countB++;
            }
            else if (selectedValue == "C")
            {
                countC++;
            }
        }
        //Response.Write("Count A :" + countA + "<br/>" +"Count B :" + countB + "Count C :" + countC);
    }
```